# Store strings as wstring or wxString in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, data-structures, wxwidgets, datastore

I have to store many strings in `class Language`. I store them as `std::wstring`. And in GUI part I'd display them in `wxListBox`. As I know, **wxWidgets** deals with `wxString`. So, how have I to store strings in `Language` by `wxString` instead of default `std::wstring` ? They said it is better, then logic part of code doesn't know anything aboud GUI part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wxWidgets documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html):

> While the use of wxString is unavoidable in wxWidgets program, you are encouraged to use the standard string classes std::string or std::wstring in your applications and convert them to and from wxString only when interacting with wxWidgets.

`wxString` has a converting constructor from `std::wstring` (amongst other things), so you can easily make one when you need one.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in this case, in memory will be `std::wstring` and `wxString` for one real string. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  You will typically construct a temporary `wxString` to pass to a wxWidgets function and then discard it afterwards (or let it go out of scope).